# How to join a buffer (point) to a line in QGIS 3.0 modeler?

Tags: qgis, buffer, qgis-processing, spatial-join, qgis-modeler

Is there a way to join an output buffer of a point to a line in QGIS 3.0 model processor? This is being added to a larger model so a standalone script wouldn't be practical.

I am not sure if this is an error that needs to be reported or if I am doing something incorrectly.

I am wanting to buffer a point and then join it to a line in QGIS 3.0 processing modeler. However I cannot set the output of the buffer as the input or join layer for the "Join Attributes by location" algorithm.

I have attempted the following things:

(1) Doing each step individually outside of processing modeler (works)

(2) Entering the input myself

(3) trying the same with a single sided buffer (works)

(4) selecting the buffers by location and then joining (I am able to select, but then not join).

(5) joining the points to transmedia before buffer (works)

[image]

Comment: Looks like that's a valid bug, thanks! It'll be fixed in 3.0.3

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a good work around? Do we know when 3.0.3 is going to be released?